# Add file type to data persistor

Tags: magento2, forms

I have a custom form that has a input type file everything works fine except for the data persistor. Its working for text input types where you can just insert the request params in the data persistor. But to be honest I don't know how to even get started on saving the file in the data persistor.

I'm saving the file with the fileUpload class but creating one makes an object that I cannot save in the data persistor.

Does someone have a solution for this? Thanks a lot!